# Spring Security's Default User Schema with Initialization Script?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

As explained in the Spring Security documentation ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#user-schema)), the *spring-security-core* library provides a *UserDetailsService* implementation, which requires that we implement some database schemas used by the framework.

If we adhere to this default configuration, then we can easily implement JDBC Authentication as follows:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .withDefaultSchema()
        .withUser(User.withUsername("user")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("pass"))
            .roles("USER"));
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

And maybe redefining some queries, if we're using something different from  HSQLDB.

The script shown above creates the user in the database, of course. Now, my question is: Is there any way to replace the programmatical DB initialization  `.withUser(...)` with a SQL script??

If I add a *data.sql* script to my resources, it tries to get executed before the schema is created and fails.

Comment: To let Spring Boot create the schema for us specify `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` in `application.properties` with Annotation `@Entity`, `@Table` at your model. To keep the previous data you can use `update` for `ddl-auto`

Comment: Thanks for commenting @PatelRomil. In this case, I'm not relying on Hibernate to create the DB schema at all, so the property isn't useful for this; the *withDefaultSchema* directive adds its own DDL file to be executed...
I guess we have to choose here, either we go with a fully programmatic approach (as I did), or fully 'scripted' approach, including both the schema.sql and the script.sql scripts